# Percent of total: Is there a more efficient way than using a subselect?

Tags: oracle, performance, aggregate, computed-column, query-performance

I have an existing `ASSET_SUMMARY_VW` view:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+
|      ASSET_TYPE       |     COST      |
+-----------------------+---------------+
| TRANSPORTATION        | 1,000,000,000 |
| TRANSPORTATION        |   500,000,000 |
| TRANSPORTATION        |   500,000,000 |
| ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION |   100,000,000 |
| ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION |    50,000,000 |
| STORMWATER MANAGEMENT |   500,000,000 |
+-----------------------+---------------+
```

I want to GROUP BY and calculate the percentage of each `ASSET_TYPE` compared to the total cost:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------+
|      ASSET_TYPE       |     COST      | PERCENT_OF_TOTAL |
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------+
| TRANSPORTATION        | 2,000,000,000 |             75.4 |
| ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION |   150,000,000 |              5.6 |
| STORMWATER MANAGEMENT |   500,000,000 |             18.8 |
+-----------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

I can divide the `COST` by a subselect that gets the total cost:

```
SELECT 
    ASSET_TYPE
    ,SUM(COST) AS COST
    ,SUM(COST/(
               SELECT 
                   SUM(COST) 
               FROM 
                   USER.ASSET_SUMMARY_VW)
               ) AS PERCENT_OF_TOTAL
FROM 
    USER.ASSET_SUMMARY_VW
GROUP BY 
    ASSET_TYPE
```

However, it's occurred to me that using a subselect is inefficient. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with data as
(
  select 'TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 2000000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 150000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'STORMWATER MANAGEMENT' as asset_type, 500000000 as cost from dual
  )
select
  data.asset_type, data.cost, 
  trunc(ratio_to_report(data.cost) over () * 100, 1) as percent_of_total
from data;

ASSET_TYPE                  COST PERCENT_OF_TOTAL
--------------------- ---------- ----------------
TRANSPORTATION        2000000000             75.4
ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION  150000000              5.6
STORMWATER MANAGEMENT  500000000             18.8
```

`RATIO_TO_REPORT` still works with your updated data:

```
with data as
(
  select 'TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 1000000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 500000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 500000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 100000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION' as asset_type, 50000000 as cost from dual union all
  select 'STORMWATER MANAGEMENT' as asset_type, 500000000 as cost from dual
  )
select
  data.asset_type, sum(data.cost), 
  trunc(ratio_to_report(sum(data.cost)) over () * 100, 1) as percent_of_total
from data
  group by data.asset_type
;

ASSET_TYPE            SUM(DATA.COST) PERCENT_OF_TOTAL
--------------------- -------------- ----------------
TRANSPORTATION            2000000000             75.4
ACTIVE TRANSPORTATION      150000000              5.6
STORMWATER MANAGEMENT      500000000             18.8
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a window aggregate over the whole result set:

```
SELECT 
    ASSET_TYPE
    ,SUM(COST) AS COST
    ,SUM(COST) / SUM(SUM(COST)) OVER () AS PERCENT_OF_TOTAL 
FROM 
    USER.ASSET_SUMMARY_VW
GROUP BY 
    ASSET_TYPE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

recommend using the NTILE command to separate the data into groups of 10 (as appropriate) and take the groups that are needed to reach the percentage that is needed.

Comment: It is not obvious how this approach answers the stated question. It would be better if you could more fully explain how your approach would work. You can edit your answer to do this.